# High FPS and timer precision for 2d graphic application

Tags: python, timer, 2d, pyqt4

I need to make desktop application part of which will be a simple 2d-graphic.
All I need to do is draw a few circles on screen that will be moving from one position to another. Like a pong game.

I already tried to make this program using Python with PyQt library for drawing and the problem is that QTimer ticks different on my laptop with Intel Core i7 2.30 GHz, 8GB RAM and on old computers, such as VirtualBox Windows XP machine with 1GB RAM and slow CPU.

For example, If i run timer with the interval 1000 / 60 ms (I think it is 60 FPS, right?), it ticks normally on laptop (time between ticks was 16 ms) but on old computer it ticks with interval 20 or 30 ms.

As far as I know it happens so because of skipping ticks when CPU can't process them with specified interval.
But I don't know what I need to do with id.

So, the question is how to achieve fast drawing and moving of simple geometrical objects on slow computers with FPS 60 as the minimum.
What language or technologies I need to use? What I'm doing wrong?